# Aws describe-instances Name and PublicIP in columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to make a list in two colums: InstanceName and PublicIp.

I run following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-central-1 --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicIpAddress,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value]" --output=table
```

and it gives me a list, but in one column.

I tried to run command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-central-1 --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[{PublicIP:PublicIpAddress},Tags[?Key=='Name'].{Value:Value}]" --output=table
```

but it gives an error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Is there a way to do that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicIpAddress, Tags[? 
  Key=='Name'].Value|[0]]" \
  --output table
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need!